# How to define a field in Solr to get the best suggestion results

Tags: indexing, solr, search-engine, autosuggest, search-suggestion

Say I have a list of about 17,000 drug names that I want to be able to search: [Acetaminophen, Ibuprofen, Xanax, percocet, etc]. I want to be able to suggest drugs from the list as a user is typing.

However, as I have it, when I type "ibup", the suggestions are
"I-123 MIBG"
"I 123 Mini"
"I-131 Mini"
"I-Prin (Oral)" etc.....
I would expect "Ibuprofen" to be one of, if not the top, result in the list of suggestions. How do I define a `field` and `fieldType` so that it works well with a suggester.

The field type of each drug name is the default text_general that comes built in:

```xml
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
      <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

I am using the FuzzyLookupFactory to suggest drug names from the list. My search component and request handler look like this:

```xml
<searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
  <lst name="suggester">
    <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
    <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
    <str name="storeDir">fuzzyDirectory</str>
    <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
    <str name="field">drugName</str>
    <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
    <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
    <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
  </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggesthandler" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy" >
  <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="suggest">true</str>
    <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
    <str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str>
  </lst>
  <arr name="components">
    <str>suggest</str>
  </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: Hello, how are you calling the suggesthandler? I built a core with all the infos you put here and when I call: /solr/stack_o/suggesthandler?indent=on&q=ibup&wt=json   I get: 1 suggestion: Ibuprofen.                                                    suggestions: [
{
term: "Ibuprofen",
weight: 0,
payload: ""
}
]